# changing animate slider to fade with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel

i have this JS that slides between images, but i want to change them to fade - whats best way to change these?

here is a full demo incase it is better: http://jsfiddle.net/mJcTA/6/

```
    animate: function () {
            var nextItem, pos;
            // check whether there are enough items to animate to
            if (this.itemIndex > (this.noOfItems - this.options.itemsPerPage)) {
                this.itemIndex = this.noOfItems - this.options.itemsPerPage; // go to last panel - items per transition
            }
            if (this.itemIndex < 0) {
                this.itemIndex = 0; // go to first
            }
            nextItem = this.items.eq(this.itemIndex);
            pos = nextItem.position();

            if (headache) {
                this.runner
.stop()
.animate({ left: -pos.left }, this.options.speed, this.options.easing);
            }
            else {
                this.mask
.stop()
.animate({ scrollLeft: pos.left }, this.options.speed, this.options.easing);
            }
            this.updateBtnStyles();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to change is the content inside

```
.animate({HERE}..
```

which changes the **left** position css property to 0. If you want to make it a fade the right animation would be to change opacity to 1:

```
.animate({opacity:1}...
```

Please note that the opacity css property is interpreted in different ways depending on browser, so you might need to change multiple "opacity" rules.

The code isn't complete, since I don't have much time to read the entire script, but this will get you going...

Comment: That is what i tried doing before but did not work, in fact the slides did not change but also no error in console so assumed i was doing it wrong but that's how i done it and how i have just done it again without success.

Comment: Ive added a demo to jsfiddle to show everything and how it works, maybe when you have some time you can lend a hand or someone else fancies it? thanks in advance